# Docker windows pull image x509: certificate signed by unknown authority

Tags: windows, docker, server

i have installed the docker in windows 2016 server VM but When i try to pull the docker image windows server core 2016 behind firewall  ( office n/w) "`docker pull Microsoft/windowsservercore"`  i am getting  x509: certificate signed by unknown authority error. But when pull the image in my home i can download the issue is its very slow. 
i have tried adding insecure-registary in deamon.jason file. but it was not in a proper format.

Let me know how i can download image from office n/w.

Regards,
Karthick

Comment: This means that your office has a proxy setup which is creating a problem. You need either get the rootCA that the proxy uses (if generating ssl certs on the fly) or you need to setup insecure registry for `registry-1.docker.io`. Read the below url for more details https://docs.docker.com/registry/insecure/. If you still have issues then update the question

Comment: @TarunLalwani: I am facing this issue with Win10. Command i used: `docker login docker.artifactory.abc.net -u tom -p pwd`. Certificate is CA signed not self-signed. Where exactly do i need to put the rooCA? I tried adding the rootCA to both `Trusted Root Certification Authorities` and `Intermediate Certification Authorities` but issue persists. I also tried creating a dir under `C:\Users\tom\.docker\machine\certs` with same name `docker.artifactory.abc.net` and then copied the `ca.crt` file inside the dir `docker.artifactory.abc.net` but still the issue persists.

Comment: You are using docker for windows in linux container mode?

Comment: No. I am using `docker-machine` on Windows 10 VM. I am just trying to login to our private container registry (Artifactory) from a Win10 VM and that's when i get the error `x509: certificate signed by unknown authority`

Comment: We also have `Docker for Windows` installed but that never worked so i've been asked to use `docker-machine`.